# Как изменить input file

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как изменить input file чтобы вместо кнопки был квадрат при нажатие на которого появляется окно выбора файла.

```css
img {
  margin: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">

<img src="" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант. Добавить `label`, а поле `input` скрыть:

```css
label {
   cursor: pointer;
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   display: block;
}

#upload-photo {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<label for="upload-photo"></label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo" />
```